# Using Python to login to a .aspx form

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, robobrowser

I'm trying to log onto a website that uses aspx. I tried everything and all the solutions from Stackoverflow. I was trying with python requests and robobrowser but both failed.

Here is the form that I got from javascript, the problem here is that there is no button to submit the form, it's just a span tag.

```
0: form#frmDefaultMaster
0: input#rsmDefaultMaster_TSM
1: select.nav-select
2: input#ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbUserName.riTextBox.riEnabled
3: input#ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbUserName_ClientState
4: input#ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbPassword.riTextBox.riEnabled
5: input#ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbPassword_ClientState
6: input#ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rbLogin_ClientState
7: input#__LASTFOCUS
8: input#__EVENTTARGET
9: input#__EVENTARGUMENT
10: input#__VIEWSTATE
11: input#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR
12: input#__EVENTVALIDATION
```

The response:

```
....
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR: CD85D8D2
__EVENTVALIDATION: QKgKEA99vPpanZgU8X6PHAHp6NosVDjGbPeekexd8iwC9n+kKHZ554FzuWjeshUTg6ezi2F4dTJER3UO0ptPsluIGkdnkkqwdE13WSlRM99GijZKCw1S4NRNdARxkJB3tf/qD+i/IGVhYLIXe3n0ehDebns8xUBxy2S5+/LymGStS8//dES8XZPt48MsSHMoWCpRs2zyWE2m7AijL9sAVg==
ctl00$contDefaultMaster$rtbUserName: USERNAME
ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbUserName_ClientState: {"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"USERNAME","valueAsString":"USERNAME","lastSetTextBoxValue":"USERNAME"}
ctl00$contDefaultMaster$rtbPassword: PASSWORD
ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbPassword_ClientState: {"enabled":true,"emptyMessage":"","validationText":"PASSWORD","valueAsString":"PASSWORD","lastSetTextBoxValue":"PASSWORD"}
ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rbLogin_ClientState: 
__ASYNCPOST: true
RadAJAXControlID: ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rapLogin
```

And finally my python code:

```
    URL = 'URL'

    username = 'USERNAME'
    password = 'PASSWORD'

    browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
    browser.open(URL)
    signin = browser.get_form(id='frmDefaultMaster')
    signin["ctl00$contDefaultMaster$rtbUserName"].value = username
    signin["ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbUserName_ClientState"].value = {"emptyMessage": "",
                                                                       "validationText": username,
                                                                       "valueAsString": username,
                                                                       "lastSetTextBoxValue": username}

    signin["ctl00$contDefaultMaster$rtbPassword"].value = password
    signin["ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rtbPassword_ClientState"].value = {"emptyMessage": "",
                                                                       "validationText": password,
                                                                       "valueAsString": password,
                                                                       "lastSetTextBoxValue": password}
    signin["ctl00_contDefaultMaster_rbLogin_ClientState"].value = ""
    browser.submit_form(signin)

    print(browser.url)

    print(signin)
```

Every time I run the browser redirects me to the error page.

Any help?

Comment: Try selenium instead

Comment: @MikhailBeliansky I tried selenium but it's slow for my needs. That is why I am trying to use requests or robobrowser.